# CSS property is not Effecting on Nested Routes on my js file

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I made css file for some simple styling. My classes in css file Content and main contact are working for Routes but these classes ore not working for my nested routes
and its 
Main.js---

```
import {Routes,Route, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'
//import {Redirect} from 'react'
import { Films } from '../Films/Films'
import { People } from '../People/People'
//import { Planet } from '../Planet/Planet'
import { Planets } from '../Planets/Planets'
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import { Person } from '../Person/Person'
import { Home } from '../Home/Home'


export const Main = (props) => {

  const { pathname } = useLocation();
  const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      if (pathname.indexOf('/people') > -1) {
        let resp = await fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people');
        let data = await resp.json();
        console.log('Fetched the people. Updating people state');
        setPeople(data.results);
      }
    })();
  }, [pathname]);




  return (
    <div className='mainContent content'>

      <Routes>
        <Route path="/films/*" element={<Films/>}></Route>
        <Route path="/planets/*" element={<Planets/>}></Route>
       
         <Route path="/people" element={<People list={people} />}>
       
          <Route path="/people/:id" element={<Person list={people} />}/>
        
            {/* Person is passed prop with fetch results */}
          </Route>
         
     
          <Route path="*" element={<Home  />}>

          </Route>
          
          </Routes>
       
         </div>
  )
}
```

My CSS File.

```
.mainContent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.mainContent > div {
  /* one column for list, one for details */
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 40vh;
}
.content{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

content class is to display extracted records detail in flex direction but it is displaying for people and person it just working for Films and Planets.
Please tell me how this content class will work for  and  routes.

Comment: Can you please create a `Stackblitz` or `CodePen` link and share it here? Also, I believe you are adding styles globally.

Comment: Hi, Thank you your response, but I've fixed, there's an error in my outlet component.